# The property can't be unconditonally accsessed because the receiver can be null, flutter localization

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, dart-null-safety

What's up some guys... I am in the process of making my app available in different countries and I am doing that with flutter_localizations and intl. Everything went smooth up until the very end where I actually use the text from the different language files. Basically I'm trying to add the localization text instead of my hardcoded text, see below.

```
var text = AppLocalizations.of(context);
Text(text.appTitle),
```

In my Text widget I get the following error:
"The property 'appTitle' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'". Is there a good workaround for this? Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Text you can do, because the `text` can be null while reading `AppLocalizations.of(context)`.

```dart
Text("${text?.appTitle}"),
```

This will show null, if it doesn't find the value.

Or checking

```dart
if(text!=null) Text("${text!.appTitle}"),
```

Use `!` when you are certain it won't be null.

Comment: More about [internationalization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization)

Comment: This solved the issue, thank you very much. Will mark as answer soon :)

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 1):

Since the value could be null at some point it's best to have a default value to display something in case there's no text to show. You can use the null check operator `??` in order to display a placeholder in case the value is null.

Your code will look something like this:

```
var text = AppLocalizations.of(context);
Text(text?.appTitle ?? 'this text is shown if app title is null')
```